# How to create .git file

Tags: linux, git, centos

My team has their repositories as .git files in various places on the filesystem, we don't use a git server.  How do you create a .git file from existing sources?

Comment: Go into source directory and do `git init`? It will create the `.git` directory in there.

Comment: OK so if I do a git init in my source directory, then check in and push, the result will be a .git file that others can clone?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking about - you probably meant to do something like documentd here: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#gitdaemon - but yes, first you need to `git init`, add the sources, commit, and do what's documented in that link to allow others to clone/pull from you.

Comment: OK I think I see what they've done, they've created .git files then renamed them to something like project1.git.  So I was under the impression there was a special procedure to create a project1.git (rather than a .git) file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
cd my_source_dir
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Now your friends with access to the same filesystem can clone it with:

```
git clone /path/to/my_source_dir new_tree_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you mean "share using gitosis" http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#gitosis

> Pushing your local repo to to the gitosis server

```
> $ cd project-X 
> $ git remote add origin gitosis@gitosis-server:project-X.git 
> $ git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

> This will create a directory project-X under
>   /var/lib/gitosis/repositories/
>
> Accessing the repository Nothing special here. If your key was added
>   to the gitosis-admin repository, then you can acces it with.

```
> $ git clone gitosis@gitosis-server:project-X.git
```